# How do you make the searchbar filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, filter, searchbar

I'm trying to make the searchbar filter items in ASP.NET C#, but is only shows the id. I want the searched item that shows on the dropdownlist when searched a list of the items will show that only contains the searched item. For example: I want to see if I look for chicken in an ingredient, only recipes will show that contains chicken.

here is my model:

```
namespace Refrigerator.Models
{
    public class Recipe
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required, DisplayName("Recept"), StringLength(45, ErrorMessage = "De {0} moet minimaal {2} tekens lang zijn.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required, DisplayName("Beschrijving"), StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "De {0} moet minimaal {2} tekens lang zijn.", MinimumLength = 10)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual List<IngredientRecipe> IngredientRecipes { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Category")] 
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        [Required]
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        [Required]
        public int Kcal { get; set; }
    }

    public class IngredientRecipe
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required, DisplayName("Recept")]
        public int RecipeId { get; set; }
        [Required, DisplayName("Ingrediënt")]
        public int IngredientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("RecipeId"), Column(Order = 1)]
        public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("IngredientId"), Column(Order = 2)]
        public virtual Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace Refrigerator.Controllers
{
    public class RecipesController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Recipes
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string[] ingredients)
        {
            var recipes = db.Recipes.Include(r => r.Category);
            if (ingredients != null)
            {
                ViewBag.ingredients = ingredients.ToList();
                return View(await recipes.ToListAsync());
            }
            return View(await recipes.ToListAsync());
        }
```

View:

```
@using System.Collections
@using Refrigerator.Controllers
@using Refrigerator.Models
@model IEnumerable<Refrigerator.Models.Recipe>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


@if (ViewBag.ingredients != null)
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col 12">
                <ul>
                    @foreach (string p in ViewBag.ingredients)
                    {
                        <li>@p</li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Your view appears to be a list of ingredients, not recipes. Your controller action takes in an array of strings. Seems like it should take in the IngredientId for chicken lets say. Then you could fetch all those recipes with something like `var recipes = db.Recipes.Include(r => r.Category).Where(r => r.IngredientRecipes.Any(i => i.IngredientId == searchIngredientId).ToList();`.